# list comprehension string alternating patern incrementing

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to have a one liner using list comprehension to generate an alternating pattern using a incrementing side number such as:

```
L = ['x0', 'y0', 'x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2']
```

So far I have managed to generate this:

```
>>> L = [f'x{i}' if i%2==0 else f'y{i}' for i in range(6)]
>>> print(L)
>>> ['x0', 'y1', 'x2', 'y3', 'x4', 'y5']
```

Does anybody have a suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the same `i` twice, so you need another *nested loop* to do the same thing with `i` for different letters:

```
[f'{c}{i}' for i in range(6) for c in 'xy']
```

Comment: Ahhhh ! so it basically running through the first range (list of number) and then the second the 'xy' list ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

This is a one liner with the desired output

```py
["{}{}".format(j,i) for i in range(3) for j in ["x","y"]]
```

output:

```
Out[3]: ['x0', 'y0', 'x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2']
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be readable, but assuming you are creating oneliner you are not going for readability.

So basically you could try the idea of nesting for{x,y} in for3, that way you still get 6 elements, but you can do x0,y0 at first iteration, x1,y1 at 2nd, x2,y2 at 3rd.

Then the append(fstring) is just a compliment to finish up the whole process.